# dedup works as shortestpath? any alternatives?

Tags: gremlin

**Sample data: TinkerPop Modern**
*(IDs wont match with my result but you can skip the ids)*

[image]

---

**Objective:
Find all Software that are somehow (in or out) connected to Marko within a limit of traversals**

**Query 1**: without dedup

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has("name", "Marko").as("from") 
.repeat(both().as("to").simplePath().barrier()) 
.emit(loops().is(lt(4)).and().hasLabel("Software")) .path().as("p") 
.select("from", "to").by("name").as("data") .select("p", "data")
```

**Result for Query 1**:

```
{'p': [v[10224], v[10220]], 'data': {'from': 'Marko', 'to': 'lop'}}
{'p': [v[10224], v[10226], v[10220]], 'data': {'from': 'Marko', 'to': 'lop'}}
{'p': [v[10224], v[10226], v[10222]], 'data': {'from': 'Marko', 'to': 'ripple'}}
{'p': [v[10224], v[10220], v[10226], v[10222]], 'data': {'from': 'Marko', 'to': 'ripple'}}
```

**Query 2**: with dedup

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has("name", "Marko").as("from")
.repeat(both().as("to").simplePath().barrier())
.emit(loops().is(lt(4)).and().hasLabel("Software"))
.dedup("from", "to")
.path().as("p")
.select("from", "to").by("name").as("data")
.select("p", "data")
```

**Result for Query 2:**

```
{'p': [v[10224], v[10220]], 'data': {'from': 'Marko', 'to': 'lop'}}
{'p': [v[10224], v[10226], v[10222]], 'data': {'from': 'Marko', 'to': 'ripple'}}
```

---

**Questions**:

- .dedup("from", "to") seems to be performing the actions of finding the shortest path between
- Is there a better way to perform shortest path? I tried doing limit(1) but maybe I was not using it properly
- My query takes a long time if i dont use .simplePath().barrier() any way to improve my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `emit()` traversal is not a break condition. Your traversal will continue until there are no more simple paths left. Also, you should `dedup()` inside `repeat()`, as it makes no sense to follow duplicate paths (based on the `from` and `to` vertices) any further.

```
g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
g.V().has("person","name","marko").as("from").
  repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from","to")).
    times(3). 
    emit(hasLabel("software")).
  hasLabel("software").
  project("p","data").
    by(path()).
    by(select(last, "from", "to").by("name"))
```

This should do what you want in the most efficient way.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has("person","name","marko").as("from").
......1>   repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from","to")).
......2>     times(3). 
......3>     emit(hasLabel("software")).
......4>   hasLabel("software").
......5>   project("p","data").
......6>     by(path()).
......7>     by(select(last, "from", "to").by("name"))
==>[p:[v[1],v[3]],data:[from:marko,to:lop]]
==>[p:[v[1],v[4],v[5]],data:[from:marko,to:ripple]]
```

Comment: trying to learn more and optimise queries, some how [barrier step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#barrier-step) is not improving the query speed, any idea why? ie. between **repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from","to"))** and **repeat(both().simplePath().barrier().as("to").dedup("from","to"))** shouldnt barrier step be faster as per documentation?

Comment: This won't change anything as `dedup()` is a barrier step anyways. Also, `simplePath()` will make things worse here as it doesn't change the traversered paths, but it will enable path tracking and thus just make things slower.